# How to use Javascript correctly to target gt table row elements in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs, gt

I am making a shiny app with a gt table.
I would like to make text in the .gt_group_heading class bold if capitalized.

It seems any text passed to this element is created within the td tag as pure text and not recognized as HTML.

So I was thinking perhaps I can alter the look of the text using Javascript?

When I run the app, I cannot get the script to work.
I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
at (index):22
```

However, when I run the app, then type the javascript directly into the browser console, I am able to get a capitalized text to appear as bold.

So is it something about shiny that is preventing the code from running correctly? It seems I need the code to run after the GT table is created, perhaps that is why the error message throws a null - but I don't know how to make that order of events happen in shiny.

FYI I have tried to wrap the strings in df$name with html tags, but this does not render correctly, i.e. the following does not work:

```
`df$name <- mutate(df$name, paste("<b>", df$name, "</b>"))`
```

Any help very much appreciated.  Here is my sample code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(shiny)

df <- tibble(

  name = c("john", "john", "jerry", "jerry", "jack", "jack", "jim", "jim"), 
  day = c("wed", "wed", "thurs", "thurs", "mon", "mon", "tues", "tues"), 
  lotto = c(12, 42, 24, 57, 234, 556, 34, 23), 
  car = c("chevy", "toyota", "honda", "gmc", "tesla", "nissan", "ford", "jeep")

) %>% 
  mutate(name = toupper(name))

options(gt.row_group.sep = "\n")

ui <- fluidPage(

  gt_output("table"),

  tags$script(
    HTML(
  
     "
    var heading = document.querySelector('#one > table > tbody > tr > td');
    var html = heading.innerHTML;
    html = html.replace(/(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b)/g,'<strong>$1</strong>');
    heading.innerHTML = html;

    "
    )
  )



)


server <- function(input, output, session){


  output$table <- render_gt(



    df %>% 
      arrange(lotto) %>%
      gt(
    
        id = "one",
        groupname_col = c("name", "day"), 
        rownames_to_stub = TRUE, 
        row_group.sep = getOption("gt.row_group.sep", "\n")
    
      ) %>%
  
      opt_css(
        css = "

    #one .gt_group_heading {

    white-space:pre-wrap;
    word-wrap:break-word;


    }

    "
      )

  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to make the group headings bold and capitalize them? And you do not want to use `text_format` and `tab_options`, but JavaScript?

Comment: I would love to find a way without using JavaScript. However, I am not aware of any way to format the text within the columns passed to groupname_col. Ideally I would like that any text with capitalized words be bold. I would love the flexibility to format the text in the groupname_col (group headings) but I don't see this functionality within gt_table, so I was trying to add javascript to the app to do so... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to delay the execution of the JavaScript code with `setTimeout`, for example 2 seconds:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var heading = document.querySelector('#one > table > tbody > tr > td');
  var html = heading.innerHTML;
  html = html.replace(/(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
  heading.innerHTML = html;
}, 2000); // 2000ms = 2s
```

It's never clear how to chose a nice value of the delay. Another possibility is to use an interval, which is executed every 100ms until it finds the object:

```js
var myinterval = setInterval(function() {
  var heading = document.querySelectorAll('#one > table > tbody > tr > td');
  if(heading) {
    clearInterval(myinterval);
    for(var i=0; i<heading.length; i++){
      var html = heading[i].innerHTML;
      html = html.replace(/(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
      heading[i].innerHTML = html;
    } 
  } 
}, 100);
```

This is the JavaScript code. But since it is sent from a string, you have to double the backslashes in the regular expression: `/(\\b[A-Z]{2,}\\b)/g`.

Comment: Thank you - unfortunately when I supply your second solution (var myinterval) to the app it does not produce the desired effect. When I check the browser console I see the following {127.0.0.1/:29 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list}. I would like every capitalized word in each .gt_group_heading element to be bold - so that all names, (john, jerry, jack, jim) are bold. Did I miss something when I pasted the code in to my app?

Comment: @mdb_ftl And the first solution, does it work? If not, there maybe a problem with the backslasches in the regular expression. Maybe one need to double or triple the backslashes.

Comment: you are correct! I needed to add extra \ to the regex - I also added a loop to target all of the td rows in the table - i have edited your solution, hope this is ok - thanks for the help